# Javascript - Mobile scroll prediction

Tags: javascript, math, browser

is it possible to 'predict' the final position after the user scrolled on mobile?
So for example, after the touchend event is fired, I get the final scrollY Position before the animation is done

Comment: Scroll height is not working?

Comment: No, it only outputs the current scroll height, but i want the position after the animation is done, before the animation get executed.

Comment: this will probably depend on your os and browser

Comment: It is fine to get an approximation of the final value. I found the fling animation from Android and I think it is the same as chrome's scroll animation. But I did'nt find an implementation of the animation. Mabye somebody knows how the algorithm works. So I can rebuild it.